# Keras hyperparameter tuning using GridSearchCV - Unable to tune 'kernel_initializer' in Dense layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, grid-search

I am new to keras and Neural networks. I am trying to tune the hyperparameters of a simple Neural network using `GridSearchCV` from scikit-learn with `keras` in python. Below is an example code for reference.

```
def base_model(input_layer_nodes = 150, optimizer = 'adam', kernel_initializer = 'normal', dropout_rate = 0.2):

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(units = input_layer_nodes, input_dim = 107, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, activation='relu'))
    Dropout(dropout_rate)

    model.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, activation='sigmoid'))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model

# Defining parameters for performing GridSearch
# optimizer = ['sgd', 'rmsprop', 'adam']
# dropout_rate = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
# input_layer_nodes = [50, 107, 150, 200]
kernel_initializer = ['uniform', 'normal']

param_grid = dict(kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer)

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = base_model, epochs = 10, batch_size = 128, verbose = 2)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs = 1, cv = 5)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

# View hyperparameters of best neural network
print("\nBest Training Parameters: ", grid.best_params_)
print("Best Training Accuracy: ", grid.best_score_)
```

When I execute the above code, I get the below error.

```
ValueError: ('Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s', dict_keys(['kernel_initializer']))
```

I am able to tune some of the other parameters of the network, like dropout_rate, optimizer, epochs. If the same code is working for other parameters, why is the kernel_initializer part not working? I am using keras 2.2.2, tensorflow 1.9.0-gpu and python 3.6.6. My OS windows 10 x64. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: can not find the error, deleted the answer ...

Comment: No problem. I am not sure what's causing this error. I have tried playing with the code to see if I can pinpoint the root cause. But no luck. I am not finding much information when I do a quick Google search too! Hopefully some of the experts here at SO can guide me. For now I have skipped tuning this parameter.